# How can you run setup files from a symbolic link in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

Create a symbolic link to a network software repository.

C:> mklink /d Software \my.network\some\software

Run C:\Software\MyProgram\Setup.exe

It fails for most installations, including Visual Studio 2008, Resharper 7, etc.

With unexpected errors or missing components.

How can this be made to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a drive letter instead of a symbolic link:

```
net use Z: \\my.network\some\software
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but doesn't really answer my question. I'm looking for a way to make symbolic links work properly, otherwise what is the point of allowing them to reference network locations?